# Can't access the method of an object inside a map

Tags: java

```
public void showTablet () {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Tablet> entry : tableMap.entrySet()) {     
        //System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        System.out.println(entry.getPrice());
    }
}
```

there is a getPrice method in a Tablet, but i can't get it? what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use,

```
entry.getValue().getPrice()
```

`entry` is of type `Map.Entry` you will have object of class `Tablet` from `entry.getValue()`

---

**See Also**

- [API Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)